# Confusion with variable update in microcontroller programming

Tags: stm32, c, variable

I use an STM32 microcontroller board and to summarize the question, in the following code inside the `if` clause the variable called `current_val` does not take the value it is assigned some lines before:

```
int main(void) {
  //initialization code
  while (1) {
    uint16_t I2C_value = get_data();

    float current_val = (I2C_value / 4096.0 - 0.5) * 50 * 1000;
    sprintf(msg_int, "%.3f \r\n", current_val);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*) msg_int, strlen(msg_int), HAL_MAX_DELAY);

    HAL_Delay(250);
        
    if (current_val > 500) {
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_10, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    }
    else {
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_10, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    }
  }
}
```

But if I declare `current_val` as global it works:

```
float current_val;

int main(void) {
  //initialization code
  while (1) {
    uint16_t I2C_value = averaging_data();

    current_val = (I2C_value / 4096.0 - 0.5) * 50 * 1000;
    sprintf(msg_int, "%.3f \r\n", current_val);
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, (uint8_t*) msg_int, strlen(msg_int), HAL_MAX_DELAY);

    HAL_Delay(250);

    if (current_val > 500) {
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_10, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    }
    else {
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_10, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    }
  }
}
```

What could be the reason in the first case `current_val` is not remaining the same after it is assigned? I don't understand what makes it change since there is nothing in the code to update its value.

Comment: Why do you think the value doesn't remain the same?

Comment: current_val becomes zero in the first case. I dont think, this is what happened.

Comment: What is `msg_int` ? Show its definition.

Comment: @EugeneSh. It is declared in main as: char msg_int[10];

Comment: And what are the values you are expecting it to get? I suspect you are overflowing it. Don't forget, it needs a space for a null-terminator as well.

Comment: If it is around `500`, (as you are comparing to it), it will be `"499.123 \r\n"` - which is already 10 characters, with no place for the terminator.

Comment: @EugeneSh. float current_val should be between -12 to 700 in my case. In the first case HAL_UART_Transmit outputs correct but after that when it comes to if the circuit didnt work so I found out current_val becomes zero. So it doesnt hold the value somehow,

Comment: As I said, if it is over 100, then your program has an undefined behavior, as your string is overflown

Comment: @EugeneSh. But why doesn't that happen in the second case? Just curicous.

Comment: Because as they (we) are saying on StackOverflow - undefined behavior is undefined :) In practice you have a different memory layout. So in one, the buffer overrun is affecting this value, in the other it is not.  You might have some other issues though. But this is a definite one. Increase the buffer  size sparingly.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Interesting. I dont have the board with me now. But I will definitely update you here after testing it tomorrow.

Comment: Morale of the story, always use snprintf

Comment: @bobflux Won't help much. It will swallow the null-terminator, and then the `strlen` will go crazy.

Comment: @bobflux it is not only printing issue it also really changes the value of the variable. Since the if condition doesnt work as expected.

Comment: @EugeneSh. snprintf() always adds the null unless you give it a zero byte buffer

Comment: @user1245 sprintf() is writting stuff after the end of the buffer, when something writes bytes in memory where they're not supposed to be, stuff can happen. If it overwrites your variable, then it'll have a different value afterwards, of course

Comment: @bobflux Right. Mixed with the other `*n*` functions, such as `strncpy`, which are not so courteous.

Comment: Morale of the story is rather: don't use PC libs like stdio.h in an embedded system. Writing some manner of serial bus or display driver isn't rocket science.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by @EugeneSh, your `sprintf` line will overflow the `msg_int` buffer whenever `current_val` reaches a value of 100.
You would have 3 digits, a dot, another 3 digits, a space, and ending with a CR-LF pair, for a total of 10 characters. But since a C string is always terminated with a \0 or "null" character, you actually need to allocate 11 bytes for your `msg_int` array, not 10.

In your first case, both `current_val` and `msg_int` are local variables on the stack of your `main` function, and will probably be allocated memory space next to each other.
So when your `sprintf` writes to `msg_int`, and `current_val >= 100`, it could end up overwriting the 1st byte of `current_val` with a 0 (the string terminator).

In your second case, although nothing has changed with the `snprintf` call overflowing `msg_int`, now that `current_val` is a global variable it gets a statically assigned memory location so it's no longer on the stack next to `msg_int` - so even though the overflow bug is still present it doesn't overwrite `current_val`, but overwrites something else instead (which may come back to bite you at some point in the future).

The solution to this is clearly to allocate an extra byte to `msg_int`, but what you should also do in future is *never* use `sprintf` to write a string to a buffer, but rather use `snprintf` instead.
The difference between them being that you give `snprintf` the size of the buffer it's writing to so that it wont ever overflow it.